# What is the practical use of arbitrary code block (by curly brackets) in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, curly-braces, paradigms

I have seen an example with the switch statement where each case block was surrounded by the curly brackets, like this:

```
switch (itemType)
{
    case ItemType.TV:
    {
        String message = Messages.GetMessage(itemType);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        break;
    }
    case ItemType.Computer:
    {
        XPMessage message = XPMessage.Next();
        if(message.Data == "XC12")
            message.IsValid = true;

        break;
    }
    case ItemType.WashingMachine:
    {
        String message = "Washing machines are so cool.";
        Messages.SendMessage(message, itemType);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The only benefit I am aware of is limiting the declaration scope (seen in the example).

However, I'd like to know if there are any other **good uses** for separating some parts of the code in such kind of a code block (and here I mean not neccessarily within the switch statement).

**When and how do you use it, and if you don't - why don't you?**

Also, is there any downside to using such blocks of code?

Comment: code is written once and **read many times**, so as to facilitate a better read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said declaration scope is one of them and also readability. Some people think it's much easier to see the braces rather than having to keep going until they see a break statement. It seems to be a personal preference. In this case it's done for scoping purposes because not all the statements use the same data type.

Comment: Also would like to thank OP for the well formatted question, they're harder to come by sometimes :)

Comment: @Ramos That's completely true. I just wish I am better with English so I could post correctly written text. And as for the formatting - better question can produce better answers. :)

Comment: Perfectly fine for me keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a stylistic thing that some people prefer for readability/white space, when not done for scope purposes.

There are no additional benefits that I am aware of.